# Python - Convert

Tags: python

I want to write a Python code that convert a user input string to numbers, such as:
`a = 01, b = 02.... z = 26` and any numbers just adds a 0 in front of them so `0 = 00, 1 = 01, etc`.

> Example: Enter `abc123` will produce `010203010203`

How would I go about doing that? I've found tons of ways to easily convert `a` to `1`, `b` to `2`, etc but adding the 0 in front complicates it.
NB: My understanding of python is very minimal

```
dictionary = {0:'00',1:'01',2:'02',3:'03',4:'04',5:'05',6:'06',7:'07',8:'08',9:'09','a':'01','b':'02','c':'03','d':'04','e':'05','f':'06','g':'07','h':'08','i':'09','j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
```

While long, would this work by making the 00, 01, etc as strings? Or is there an easier or better way? I'm not even sure if that will work above.

Comment: "I'm not even sure if that will work above" you could test it?

Comment: That isn't the question I asked, but thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick if I understand your problem, although it's probably not "best practice"...

```
test = "abc123z"
new_strs = []
for char in test:
  try:
    int(char)
    new_strs.append(f"0{char}")
  except:
    num = ord(char) - 96
    new_str = f"{num}" if num > 9 else f"0{num}"
    new_strs.append(new_str)

new_str = ''.join(new_strs)
assert new_str == "01020301020326"
```

Comment: Wow perfect, that works wonderfully. I wasn't expecting you to do all that work, but I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This won't work for letters that require two digits, e.g. `z` will be `026`. I also don't understand why you're using RegEx when you can just iterate the string normally. `for character in string`

Comment: @iz_ I removed the regex and updated to account letters > i

Comment: @NickMartin Thanks, nice answer! It's not a big deal (correctness is much more important), but it's typically better to use more efficient methods of string concatenation - see https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Comment: @iz_ Updated again with your suggestions :-)

Comment: I think the article is trying to point out that naive concatenation with `+=` is not the way to go... Anyway, it doesn't really matter. Efficiency should only be a concern when it needs to be.

Comment: @iz_ 119,800 concatenations per second! :D

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a basic Python understanding. So, I come here with a basic style to achieve your goal.

First, in your dictionary, you have to change the inetegers keys to make them string, i.e. `0` become `"0"`. You do the same to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9.

Now, here is the final code:

```
user_input = input("Your input: ")
d = {'0':'00','1':'01','2':'02','3':'03','4':'04','5':'05','6':'06','7':'07','8':'08','9':'09','a':'01','b':'02','c':'03','d':'04','e':'05','f':'06','g':'07','h':'08','i':'09','j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}

user_input = user_input.strip()

results = []

for ch in user_input:
    results.append(d[ch])

final_result = ''.join(results)
print(final_result)
```

> **Input:** `abc123`
>
> **Output:** `010203010203`

Comment: I change `dictionary` name to `d` for simplicity.